# React function to wrap a jsx element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a function that will return a jsx element wrapped with  and  elements. How to do this?

In my code, I have a lot of the following:

```
<Top />
<Home />
<Bottom />

<Top />
<About />
<Bottom />

<Top />
<Contact />
<Bottom />

<Top />
<Blog />
<Bottom />

<Top />
<API />
<Bottom />
```

etc.

How can I make a function which takes say `<Home />` as an input parameter and returns a wrapped jsx element?

I've tried:

```
function wrap(???){
  return (
    <Top />
    //what goes here????
    <Bottom />
  )
}
```

I'm afraid I'm still getting used to the syntax and can't figure it out

Comment: Don't you need just to pass a React.Component object to wrap() and insert {component} where you put the comment?

Comment: Thanks @Carlo, but I'm afraid I can't figure out the required syntax... ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you need to wrapp the return with a root element, a div for exp, or a Fragment which is released in React 16.2, in this exp i used a div:

```
function wrap(Wrapped) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Top />
        <Wrapped />
      <Bottom />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Edited:** you could use the render children method also:

```
const WrapperExp = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>top</h1>
          {props.children}
        <h1>bottom</h1>
      </div>
    )
};

const App = () => (
  <WrapperExp>
    <h2>tada...</h2>
  </WrapperExp>
);
```

take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7pp9zn879) exp.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be

```
function wrap(component) {
  return (
    <Top />
      {component}
    <Bottom />
  );
}
```

and maybe if you use `wrap` in a `render` method

```
render() {
  const aComponent = (<Home/>);
  return (
    {wrap(aComponent)}
  );
}
```

Comment: Interesting... Excellent!